# Програмный клик по сслыке в TWebbrowser Delphi

Tags: delphi

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать програмный клик по ссылке

```
<a class="user__link log" href="https://ххyyzz./user-ads" title="Вход" target="_blank">Войти...</a>
```

в TWebbrowser с помощью delphi. Возможно ли после перехода открыть страницу на которую ссылается линк в том же браузере ввиду наличия `target="_blank"` в теге?

**Update**
Проблема в том что на сайте присутствует авторизация. после прохождения которой перекидывает на обычную страничку, а не в кабинет. Чтоб войти в кабинет необходимо пройти по указанной выше ссылке с куками, выданными после авторизации, а при прямом Navigate() по указанному урлу Cookies теряются и Twebbrowser автоматически возвращает на страничку авторизации

Comment: Куки не должны теряться, это странно. А если "не-программно" кликнуть на ссылку - всё открывается правильно? Укажите заодно - FMX или VCL?

Comment: @kami - VCL, если "не-программно" кликнуть на данную ссылку - все открывается правильно (правда пришлось перевести открытие страницы в новый экземпляр TWebbrowser из-за `target="_blank"` но к этому попозже вернусь.)

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно кликать по ссылке. Сделайте простой `Navigate()` по нужному адресу

Если `Navigate` теряет куки, то попробуйте так

```
myWB.document.location.href := 'http://...'
```

Или для FMX

```
myWB.EvaluateJavaScript('location.href="http://..."');
```

Comment: Проблема в том что на сайте присутствует авторизация. после прохождения которой перекидывает на обычную страничку, а не в кабинет. Чтоб войти в кабинет необходимо пройти по указанной выше ссылке с  куками, выданными после авторизации, а при прямом Navigate() по указанному урлу Cookies теряются и Twebbrowser автоматически возвращает на страничку авторизации

Comment: [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(319): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'EvaluateJavaScript'  TWebBrowser doesn't contain a member named 'EvaluateJavaScript'

Comment: @Asturion Обновил ответ

Comment: Сама по себе конструкция `myWB.document.location.href := 'http://...'` выдает [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(320): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'location' но если сделать
`doc := myWb.Document ;
doc.location.href := 'https:// .....'`
 то все равно навигация происходит обратно на страницу авторизации а не на страницу кабинет.

Пробовал с помощью Indy запросов делать, все работает, в кабинет заходит и позволяет выполнять действия, но заказчик просит визуализация действий при заполнении форм с возможностью править поля заполнения.

Comment: @Asturion Посмотрите в сниффере какие заголовки уходят от Вас на сервер. Куки должны передаваться

Comment: они то передаются но без данных по сессии, только геолокация, нехватает PHPSESSID=... и AuthenticatedVisitor=.... Пробовал делать запрос на Инди и подставлять куки в TWebBrowser но увы все тоже самое

Comment: @Asturion А если Вы мышей кликаете в ссылку, все работает?

Comment: В том то и дело что работает и переходит в кабинет, правда открывается в новом окне пока решил проблему так. `webbrowser2 := TEmbeddedWB.Create(Self);  TWinControl(WebBrowser2).Visible :=true;  ppDisp := webbrowser2.ControlInterface; webbrowser2.parent:=form1;
  Self.InsertControl(webbrowser2); webbrowser2.Align:=alClient; myWb.Visible:=false;`  Уже подумываю может Javascript прикрутить на выполнение.